# Custom routing with nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I have a component which checks a path name and acts on it:

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const path = router.pathname;//props.location.pathname;

  const p = path.split('/').filter((s) => s !== "")
  let submissionId = p[0] == 's' && p[1]
  const submission = useQuery(SUBMISSION, {
    variables: {
      id: submissionId
    },
    skip: submissionId === false
  })
```

This works fine in a bog standard react app but nextjs redirects toa  404.

Is tehre a way to set up a pattern for nextjs to ignore none-existant routes and allow the component code to handle it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood clearly what you want, but you need to have defined page in the **pages** folder if you don't want Next.js to redirect to 404. However, you could use **[dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routes)** to make component which will do what you want.

Create a file named **[dynamic].js** in the **pages** folder:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Dynamic = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { dynamic } = router.query;

  return (
    <div>
      My dynamic page slug: {dynamic}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dynamic
```

And you can link to it like this:

```
<Link href="/[dynamic]" as="/dynamic-page-slug">
  <a>Link to my Dynamic Page</a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using zeit now v2 then you can check out the [Wildcard Routes](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/routes#wildcard-routes) here.

Basically in your `now.json` will have a filesystem handler and a wildcard handler as below

```
{
  "routes": [
    { "handle": "filesystem" },
    { "src": "/.*", "status": 404, "dest": "SOME_PAGE_HERE" } // <-- this is where all the non-existent routes will be routing to

  ]
}
```

Just replace the `SOME_PAGE_HERE` with your route as what you have declared in `exportPathMap` from the file `next.config.js`. 
Example: `/contact`, `about-us` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In your server.js, add the following:

```
// server.js
const { createServer } = require('http');
const next = require('next');
const routes = require('./routes');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(handler).listen(port, err => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
});
```

Then in your routes.js file define your custom routes:

```
// routes.js
const nextRoutes = require('next-routes');
const routes = (module.exports = nextRoutes());

routes
    .add('landing', '/')
    .add('profile', '/profile', 'profile');
```